# contributing to IRA after tax

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira

So I'm pass the income threshold to contribute to a ROTH IRA, but I understand I can always contribute to an IRA up to the limits...

but my question is... since I can't deduct the contribution... doesn't it mean that I will be double taxed on the principle? It seems like when you take money from IRA after 65, everything is counted as income. So if I put in $5,000, when I take that money out, I have to pay taxes on that again? Am I being double taxed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make a "non-deductible" Traditional IRA contribution. You must report non-deductible Traditional IRA contributions on Form 8606 part I for the year the contribution counts under.

The after-tax principal amount (the "basis") will not be taxed upon withdrawal; only the earnings (which are always pre-tax in Traditional IRA, even if it grew from after-tax funds) and deductible contributions will be taxed upon withdrawal. (Note that a withdrawal from Traditional IRA will generally consist of pre-tax and after-tax amounts in equal proportion to the pre-tax and after-tax amounts in the Traditional IRA overall, due to the pro-rata rule.) You will calculate the taxable part of a distribution from Traditional IRA in Form 8606 part I in the year you withdraw.

Assuming you did not have any previous money in pre-tax IRAs, one thing you can do is a "back-door Roth IRA contribution" -- after you make your non-deductible contribution, immediately convert the amount to Roth IRA (this also does not have income limits). The end result (again, assuming you did not have any previous money in pre-tax IRAs, so you don't have issues with the pro-rata rule) is the same as a regular Roth IRA contribution, which is better than a non-deductible Traditional IRA contribution because the earnings are after-tax too.

Comment: The last paragraph needs to _emphasize the first clause_ of the first sentence. Money taken out of the IRA to do the backdoor Roth conversion is _also_ subject to the pro rata rule, and for the purposes of the pro rata rule, **all** the Traditional IRA accounts, _no matter where they are invested or who the custodian is_, are considered to be just one IRA. So, taking out the money just invested in a newly established Traditional IRA account to do a backdoor Roth conversion does not work if there are other Traditional IRA accounts lying around.